# Delete an ordinary shortcut on my desktop using command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I am just learning command prompt. I want to delete a shortcut on my desktop using command prompt but it says the file could not be found. The path and other things are OK. The shortcut is orbit downloader so I use

> del orbit.ink

but it says the file could not be found. I can delete it by right click, but I want to learn this procedure too. What is the problem?

Comment: Woah a longgg sentence... But anyway, are you sure you're in the right path? cd desktop? Have you checked that the extension .ink is the same as the file?

Comment: Please show us the command you used.  The path to the desktop is usually something like this "C:\Users\Your_Name\Desktop".  Did you use the full path name?

Comment: Hi.the path is "C:\users\omid\desktop" and the cammand is "del orbit.ink"

Comment: @Omid Did you 'cd C:\users\omid\desktop' and then do the del? Try doing a 'dir/l' Do you see the file listed? Oh did you use  "del orbit.ink" or "del orbit.lnk"?  It should be '.lnk'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 'orbit.lnk' <- 'L', not 'I'

Comment: @Omid Note that you can press "tab" after you type the first few characters of a filename to autocomplete the name (with the correct spelling). If more than one file starts with the letters you've already typed, keep pressing tab to cycle through them. Also the `dir` command can be used to list the files in the current directory; another way to check their actual names.

Comment: Thank you Jim G and Jason C.The problem has been solved.I was using ".ink" instead of ".lnk".I apologize all for wasting their time.some fonts have capital "I" really close to "l".That was the reason which made me confused.